# How can I position items in each box so they are consistent?

Tags: html, css

I have tried using inline styles such as

```
#whiteRectangle{
top:5% 
}
```

to try and move it manually but this is not working.

My code pen listed above shows what I have tried so far and what the problem looks like. Any guidance in getting the text and white rectangle moved for the fifth box would be greatly appreciated.

Second but smaller issue: Each text inside each box is not the same as the text shown in the design above. That is, for example we have

I have tried removing 
     text-align:center

but the issue still persists so any pointers on this second issue would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: Don't remove text-align:center; instead, add text-align:left; to that element. Also, you may want to crop the image down to just the relevant pieces. This is an overwhelming question

Comment: yeah text-align:left moves the whole thing (the text and the white rectangle) all the way to the left edge of each box

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align the white line (whiteRectangle), wrap the text in a div. You can also get rid of the br tag for "Apps" and play around with the CSS top section I provided.

```
<div class="lineup"> 
  Facebook <br/> 
  Competition <br/> 
  Apps <br/> 
  <div class="whiteRectangle"> 
</div>
```

Then add the following to your CSS

```
.lineup{
  position: relative;
  top:-20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'll accept this as a solution, but if you want the three 'white rectangles' to be in line, you could add another `br` tag on top of the content of the the two boxes beside it.

```
    <br /> 
    Facebook <br/>
    Outreach <br/>
```

and

```
    <br />
    Facebook <br/>
    Networking <br/>
```

Another solution would wrap the whole content of the boxes, set its `position` to be `absolute`, then set a fixed value for `bottom`.